# Is it possible to cache the images returned from the imagewebp function?

Tags: php

There is a php file that resizes the image and converts it to webp using the [imagewebp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php) function.

```php
// resize.php
<?php
$filename = "../" . $_REQUEST["file"];
$w = 700;
$h = 400;
$baseImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($image, $baseImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h);
imagewebp($image);
```

This resize.php can be used as follows to display resized webp images.

```php
<img src="/resize.php?file=/example.jpg">
```

However, currently the images returned from this resize.php do not have `cache-control` set.
So, I would like to have the image returned from resize.php cached.

---

The response header is as follows.
[image]
The image returned by resize.php has no `cache-control` set.

However, the normal webp file was able to set `cache-control`.
[image]

If the image does not exist as a file, can it be cached?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php ...?

Comment: (And you should probably add caching of the actual resized image itself as well, instead of resizing it every time.)